# "rm" command defaults "--preserve-root" option?

Tags: rm

They say `rm` command defaults to the option `--preserve-root`. Is that right?

Otherwise I should put the line

```
alias rm='rm --preserve-root'`
```

in `~/.bashrc` to make that option happen without typing it every time I run the `rm` command. To confirm this I ran `type rm`, and got `rm is hashed (/bin/rm)`.

I expected `rm is aliased to rm --preserve-root`. Does anyone know what's going on with the `rm` command?

Comment: sorry I have no idea who "they" are, but I think you'll find it depends on your kernel & shell/bash version. I know some of the systems I use (which are still supported) don't have --preserve-root on `rm`.

Comment: Oh, I said they cause I'm reading a book, whose name is like Ubuntu Unlished 2017 or something. I thought saying specific book name makes me look like book seller, so I did like that. My ubuntu version is Ubuntu 16.04. I still want to know how to confirm whether --preserve-root is default or not.

Comment: At least for me I get for `sudo rm -r /` the following message: `rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on '/'` and `rm: use --flag-i-wont-mention to override this failsafe`

Comment: Yeah, I also wanted to test it. However I was afraid it might cause catastrophe. Thanks man.

Comment: This is also present in the manpage for `rm`.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing was when I asked for confirmation on command line by typing "type rm" it was not what is expected like the question. Anyhow Dan cleared everything. Thanks guys.

Comment: @guiverc It has nothing to do with the kernel, or your shell (`bash` or otherwise). It's a default option in GNU `rm` since some years, which is a separate program from your shell. (It's in `coreutils` in Debian and Ubuntu).

Comment: rm -rf / is almost always executed unintentionally so they added a safeguard.

Comment: For those who are wondering, the '--preserve-root' was made the default for rm in core-utils on 2016-09-02 in: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commitdiff;h=89ffaa19;hp=963d29f9

Comment: See also `info rm`, specifically https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Treating-_002f-specially.html for some background (generally GNU commands have more details in `info` than in `man` pages).  As it explains, some related commands like `chmod` kept the historic `--no-preserve-root` behavior.

Comment: @qneill you mean 2006

Comment: Dang @ychaouche yeah good catch, wish I could edit comments, it was kind of the whole point :).  Note to self: future proof your comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`rm` is not being aliased to `rm --preserve-root`, but the option is selected by default in the `rm` binary.

From the [manpage of rm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/rm.1.html) in Ubuntu 17.10, you can find the following details of the `--preserve-root` and `--no-preserve-root` options:

```
   --no-preserve-root
          do not treat '/' specially

   --preserve-root
          do not remove '/' (default)
```

Comment: I have read man page, but I totally missed the "(default)". Thanks for the reply. BTW when you mention 'rm binary', did you mean rm is programmed in that way??

Comment: @Smile Yes, that's what it means.