# Protect folder from accidental deletion with `rm`

Tags: command-line, permissions, filesystem, rm

I have some folder `~/foo` which I'd like to protect from accidental deletion, that is I'd like to protect it from deleting with `rm -r ~/foo` or `rmdir ~/foo`.

I realized you can do that using `chmod a-w ~/foo` or `chattr -i ~/foo` but this has the drawback that you cannot change anything inside that folder. I however would still like to be able to create/move/delete files and folders *inside* `~/foo`.

Is it somehow possible to do so?

Comment: Why don't maintain a backup of the folder in question, so you can easily restore after accidental deletion?

Comment: @mook765 I do have a backup, but if I can prevent deleting it in the first place it would save me a little bit of hassle. It is not really a problem but I just did it twice in a row (d'oh:).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a hidden file inside the folder and do (`.foo` as an example) as "root":

```
touch ~/foo/.foo
chattr +i ~/foo/.foo
```

You can now delete all files except `.foo` in this directory, and the directory can not be deleted by another user. You can still move the directory though and you can stop that with the sticky bit...

```
sudo chmod +t ~/foo
```

And that should cover your problem. BUT I do agree: making a backup is always the better option. A somewhat more difficult option: put a directory watcher on `~/foo` and create a timestamped backup of every file touched and before it is altered in a directory users can not reach would be a safer method.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest adding the following "safetynets" to your .bashrc (or config file for another shell) to prevent the most obvious mistakes.

Ask for confirmation before removing 3 or more files, or any directory recursively. Also prevents removal of `/` recursively: *(the `-I` parameter is less intrusive than `-i` which prompts on every file, but still prevents most mistakes by a single confirmation prompt)*

```
alias rm='rm -I --preserve-root'
```

Prevent changing permissions and ownership on `/` recursively: *(not your question, but still a nice safety feature to include)*

```
alias chmod='chmod --preserve-root'
alias chown='chown --preserve-root'
alias chgrp='chgrp --preserve-root'
```

Comment: [`--preserve-root` is the default for `rm`](https://askubuntu.com/a/982126/550790)